# Google Authenticator SSH password or key

Tags: ssh

I have set up libpam-google-authenticator according to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04

It works, but the problem is that I can't log in with a password, it need to be with a key. If there is no key, I get permission denied public key without even being asked for a password. How can I get it to work with a public key + two factor OR password + two factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somewhat came up with a solution.

First, create a user with no password, something like:

```
sudo adduser backup --disabled-password
```

then in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User backup
    AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
    ForceCommand sudo login
```

and at the bottom of `sudo visudo`:

```
backup ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/login
```

Finally, run

```
google-authenticator
```

as the user `backup`. Or, you could copy your

```
.google_authenticator
```

file to the new user.

Now, whenever I need to login without my private key, I ssh into the user `backup`, enter my two-factor code, then I get the system login prompt that allows me to login to my main user.